# error: [Dagger/MissingBinding]. Cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dagger, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to use Hilt to inject weather repository into my view model, but get the following error message:

> WeatherRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
> public abstract static class SingletonC implements WeatherApplication_GeneratedInjector

**Weather DAO:**

```
@Dao
interface WeatherDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertWeatherItem(weatherItem: WeatherItem)
    @Query("DELETE FROM WEATHERITEM WHERE cityName = :cityName")
    suspend fun deleteWeatherItem(cityName: String)
    @Query("SELECT * FROM WEATHERITEM WHERE cityId = :id")
    fun getWeatherItem(id: Int): Flow<WeatherItem>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM WEATHERITEM")
    fun getAllWeatherItems(): Flow<List<WeatherItem>>
}
```

**Weather Repository:**

```
class WeatherRepository(private val weatherDao: WeatherDao) {
     suspend fun insertWeatherItem(weatherItem: WeatherItem) = weatherDao.insertWeatherItem(weatherItem)
     suspend fun deleteWeatherItem(cityName: String) = weatherDao.deleteWeatherItem(cityName)
     fun getWeatherItem(id: Int): Flow<WeatherItem> = weatherDao.getWeatherItem(id)
     fun getAllWeatherItems(): Flow<List<WeatherItem>> = weatherDao.getAllWeatherItems()
}
```

**Weather Database:**

```
@Database(entities = [WeatherItem::class] ,version = 1)
abstract class WeatherDatabase :RoomDatabase(){
    abstract fun weatherDao(): WeatherDao
}
```

**Weather Module:**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object WeatherModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): WeatherDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            WeatherDatabase::class.java,
            "WeatherDatabase")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
    }
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideWeatherDao(weatherDatabase: WeatherDatabase): WeatherDao {
        return weatherDatabase.weatherDao()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideWeatherRepository(weatherDao: WeatherDao): WeatherRepository {
        return WeatherRepository(weatherDao)
    }
}
```

**Weather View Model:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class WeatherViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val weatherRepository: WeatherRepository,
) : ViewModel()
```

**Main Activity:**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val viewModel: WeatherViewModel by viewModels()

        setContent {
           
            WindSpellTheme(darkTheme = darkTheme) {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MainScreen(viewModel) {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Application:**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class WeatherApplication: Application()
```

Hilt version is 2.47

**NOTE**

When navigating to *Find usages*, it's shown that there is a reference to the injected object:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try removing `@Inject constructor` from `class WeatherRepository @Inject constructor(private val weatherDao: WeatherDao)` as you already have it in the `WeatherModule`.

For now it should work.

**P.S.** If you later decide to make `WeatherRepository` an interface with its implementation, say, `WeatherRepositoryImpl`, you can do it as follows:

```
@Singleton
class WeatherRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(private val weatherDao: WeatherDao): WeatherRepository {
    //implementation
}
```

and then, in some `Module` that is an *interface* or *abstract class*:

```
@Binds
@Singleton
fun bindWeatherRepository(impl: WeatherRepositoryImpl): WeatherRepository
```

Comment: I followed your first advice, but now I receive the same type of error but for the WeatherRepository

Comment: `I followed your first advice, but now I receive the same type of error but for the WeatherRepository` what does this mean ? you've only mentioned the WeatherRepository in your post, so is there code you haven't included here or what ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody the first version of my question included @Inject constructor:
`class WeatherRepository @Inject constructor(private val weatherDao: WeatherDao)`

Comment: @YauheniMokich please try using `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)` for `WeatherModule` instead of `ActivityComponent::class`